# Gathering NDR Email addresses

Tags: vba, outlook

I am looking to gather all NDRs from out an outlook account and write the email addresses of the fails to either a table within a database or even just an excel document for the purposes of data cleaning.

Has anyone done anything like this previously and would be willing to push me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you didn't say if you wanted an open source app (not aware of any), but I have written this commercial product:

http://www.ListNanny.NET

ListNanny will extracted the bounced addresses, classify the NDR, and provide you with some helpful information on why it bounced.

The only catch is that the email needs to be in it's RFC2822 format (like you donwload over IMAP or POP3). It can't read native Outlook .msg files.

Does that help?

Comment: Hi Dave,
Thanks for getting back to me - I will have a look through and take this to my boss as a possible solution although I have a feeling that he will be after something that can read the .msg files directly.

Comment: Link is broken. Does that have a new page these days?